# AngularJS Material: no scrollbar in custom components

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

Recently I discovered AngularJS Material framework and now I'm trying to use it. For the 1st time I found no similar thread so I dare to ask. When I add my custom components like this:

```
<body ng-app="katalogApp" layout="column">
    <katalog></katalog>
</body>
```

...everything works pretty well besides flex scrolling. After pasting the component template directly in App:

```
<body ng-app="katalogApp" layout="column">
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-whiteframe-4dp" layout="column">
    it has a scrollbar
        </md-sidenav>
        <md-content flex>
            content
        </md-content>
    </div>
</body>
```

...it works but that's dirty as hell. If I add css:

```
md-sidenav {position:fixed!important}
```

to the container - there's a scrollbar but the content is misplaced. I would be grateful if someone knows how to deal with it.

[Here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jQ644aPw0AWE5Ik5mmqD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of positioning md-sidenav tag, what you can do is give height to sidenav so it'll have scrollbar & accordingly have height to main content also. Now you can add new class to md-sidenav with css as:

```
.leftSideNav {
  height: 100vh;
}
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

Where I've added these classes to md-sidenav & md-content respectively:

```
<body ng-app="katalogApp" layout="column">
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-whiteframe-4dp leftSideNav" layout="column">
    it has a scrollbar
        </md-sidenav>
        <md-content flex class="content">
            content
        </md-content>
    </div>
</body>
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eZR0DH5EYRRwdnqUoiTV?p=preview)